# How to pass argument by new operator overload to a specific function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator

I need to add customized allocation by overloading `new`, let's say for example:

```cpp
void *operator new(const size_t size, MemeoryManager *ptr) {
    ptr->allocate(size);
}

class Test {
public:
     Test(int x,int y) {}
};

int main () {
    Test *ptr = new Test(1,2);
}
```

My area of interest in `Test *ptr = new Test(1,2)` is this `1` and `2` passed here. How can I get these values in my `new` operator overload and pass them to my custom `MemoryManager::allocate()` function?

Comment: Expression `new` calls `operator new` to allocation the memory - all you get in `operator new` is the requested size (and alignment). When the memory has been allocated expression `new` calls the constructor with any parameters. See both links here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/new

Comment: why do you want to do this? Constructor parameters are for the contstructor, what would you do with them in `operator new` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number basically i have allocated memory somewhere else now i just want whenever new is called it check either i have memory available if it is it should call the copy constructor of that object instead it allocates memory by using new that is why i want to access `1` and `2` so that i can pass them to the already exisisting object

Comment: @UmarFarooq `new`s job is to create a new object, trying to subvert that is probably not a good/workable idea.  It sound like you are writing an object cache, if so just use a factory method to return an already existing object or create a new one.

Comment: @RichardCritten i agree with you but as you can see from the code now new is overloaded and i want to access the values passed to this new operator . Is there any possible way i can do it?

Comment: @UmarFarooq No - complete list of overloads for `operator new` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: `operator new` allocates chunks of memory. A chunk of memory has only one parameter: the size. `operator new` does not create an object. `new`-expression creates an object. `new`-expression and `operator new` are two different things, despite having similar names. Wanting to pass constructor arguments to `operator new` is about as sensible as wanting to pass `printf` arguments to `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The way of doing what you want would be this:

1. Have a *create function*.

   ```
    Test* create_test(int x, int y);
   ```
2. Have the create function pass the arguments to the allocator.

   ```
    Test* create_test(int x, int y) {
       void* memory = getTestMemoryManager()->allocate(x, y);
   ```
3. Placement-new your object in the memory obtained from the allocator.

   ```
    Test* create_test(int x, int y) {
       void* memory = getTestMemoryManager()->allocate(x, y);
       Test* ret = new(memory) Test(x, y);
       return ret;
    }
   ```
4. (Optional) Make `Test` constructors private, and make `create_test` a friend (or a static member), so that no one can bypass the allocator.

Whether wanting to do this is reasonable is a separate question, but if you want it, here's how you do it. You can pass the memory manager to `create_test` as an  argument if you want, or obtain it from elsewhere as show in the example.